# what is the transformation ratio of squirrel cage Machine?

Tags: rotor

typically Induction machine also called rotating transformer so what is the ratio of stator numbers of turns to rotor number of turns (from the design point of view i.e we can't directly measure secondary voltage) ?

what is the number of effective rotor(cage) turns ?

Comment: This question is completely out of a context.

Comment: @Sabri be professional and capitalize and punctuate. Be specific please. We have no idea what your talking about. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idealized picture of the squirrel cage inside an induction motor: -

[image]

Because of the aluminium end rings the aluminium bars are shorted out thus they form a single turn.

Some induction motors have dual windings that may have more than 1 turn. This is usually on large motors and helps the starting torque,

Comment: A very clear and concise answer to a poorly worded question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the explanation of Andy.
The rotor of the motor rotates a little slower then the stator field. The difference in speed is called slip. This slip is required to maintain a changeing field in the rotor. No changeing field would mean no induction and the motor would not be able to deliver any torque. That is why this type of motor is also called asynnchronous motor. Since there is an induction from the stator to the rotor at a very low frequency you can see this as a rotating transformer